# Creating a thread pool using boost

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, boost-thread

Is it possible to create a thread pool using boost's thread?
i was looking all over boost's libs and I couldn't find a thread pool manager (or something like that)...
Is there a way to do it?

tnx!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500404/how-to-create-a-thread-pool-using-boost-in-c

Comment: I posted a threadpool example using boost::asio here.

[Thread Pool Example with boost::asio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835009/c-threadpool-is-not-running-parallel/31835802#31835802

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a thread pool using boost in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500404/how-to-create-a-thread-pool-using-boost-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an unofficial (yet) [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) in boost.
But it's not a problem to implement one yourself especially if great genericity is not a primary goal. Idea: your threadpool can be parametrized with TaskType type and the number of workers. The TP must be given the handler function which takes TaskType. TP contains a queue of added tasks. The real thread function just takes a task from the queue and calls the passed handler. Something like that.

Comment: I was hoping they already added the threadpool library.. Any idea if it is going to be added soon? thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Comment: I don't know for sure but I am guessing and hoping that both ThreadPool and Process will be in 1.45

Comment: The threadpool library looked nice; too bad the documentation is lacking (many pages state TODO and warn that the description is out of date).  Looks like it hasn't received much attention since 2008.

Answer (score 36):

I know an answer has been accepted, if you need this right now, and you can't be bothered to write your own thread pool, you could try using boost asio io_service with a concurrency hint (i.e. how many threads it should run) and then post() stuff to this io_service... just an idea..

Comment: Using boost asio is the right way to go. Better not to manage the thread pool directly. Same way Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB) does.

Comment: Can u add more about it? it sounds very interesting!

Comment: I posted my thread pool example that is based on the Asio Recipes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835009/c-threadpool-is-not-running-parallel/31835802#31835802