# Multiprocessor Boost::Thread? All threads running on one processor

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing, boost-thread

I have a embarrassingly parallel problem that I want to execute on multiple processors.  I had supposed that `boost::thread` would automatically send new threads to new processors, but all of them are executing on the same core as the parent process.  Is it possible to get each thread to run on a different processor, or do I need something like MPI?

My suspicion is that `boost::thread` is simply not a multi-processor tool, that I'm asking it to do something it's not designed for.

EDIT: my question boils down to this: Why do all the threads execute on one processor?  Is there a way to get `boost::thread` to send threads to different processors?

Here's the relevant sample of my code:

```
size_t lim=1000;
std::deque<int> vals(lim);
std::deque<boost::thread *> threads;
int i=0; 
std::deque<int>::iterator it = vals.begin();
for (; it!=sigma.end(); it++, i++) {
  threads.push_back(new boost::thread(doWork, it, i));
  while (threads.size() >= maxConcurrentThreads) {
    threads.front()->join();
    delete threads.front();
    threads.pop_front();
  }
}
while(threads.size()) {
  threads.front()->join();
  threads.pop_front();
}
```

As should be clear, `doWork` does some calculation using the parameter `i` and stores the result in `vals`.  My idea was that setting `maxConncurrentThreads` to be equal to the number of cores available, and then each thread would use the core that was idle.  I just need someone to confirm that `boost::thread` cannot be made to work in this way.

(I'd guess that there's a better way to limit the number of concurrent threads than using a queue; feel free to scold me for that as well.)

---

Here's the `doWork` function:

```
void doWork(std::deque<int>::iterator it, int i) {
  int ret=0;
  int size = 1000; // originally 1000, later changed to 10,000,000
  for (int j=i; j<i+size; j++) {
    ret+=j;
  }
  *it=ret;
  return;
}
```

---

EDIT: As Martin James suggested, the problem was that the doWork function was initially only 1000 int additions.  With such a small job, scheduling the thread took longer than executing the thread, so only one processor was in use.  Making the job longer (adding 10,000,000 ints) yielded the desired behavior.  The point being: `boost::thread` *will* use multiple cores by default, but if your threads do less work than scheduling the thread then you won't see any benefit from multithreading.

Thanks to everyone for aiding my understanding in this.

Comment: Right, multiple threading and multiprocessing are quite different concepts, and boost::thread supports the former.

Comment: Sounds like MPI to me... welcome to my world !

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with MPI, he is only mixing the words multiprocessor and multicore system.

Comment: @juanchopanza I understand you to be saying that `boost::thread` cannot be made to send each thread to a different core.  Is that right?

Comment: I would be surprised if DoWork() took any longer than a couple us.  This is much, much less than the overhead load of creating the thread in the first place.  Most of the work is being done by the one thread that is doing the continual create, join, wake up again almost immmediately, loop...

Comment: No, that isn't what I meant. Different cores are fine, different processors not so.

Comment: I may have to try this :((  What do you have 'maxConcurrentThreads' set to currently?

Comment: @juanchopanza ah.  Clearly, I'm no expert.  Hence my question :)

Comment: @MartinJames it's set to 6.  I added a statement to check the size of the `threads` queue after the loop and it says it's got 5 elements, as expected.

Comment: have you checked the number of cores you see with `boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I didn't, but I printed it out and it says 8, which is the number of cores on my machine.

Comment: I was looking at `top` and it only showed one process, but i failed to notice that that process was using 600% CPU.

Comment: Usually, you can tell if something like this is working by listening.  If I load up my box with 8 100% CPU threads, the CPU fan revs up within a couple of seconds.

Comment: @MartinJames Heh.  I'll have to remember that. (Of course, the server is separated from me by a few buildings, some concrete, and my over-ear headphones, but I bet if I listen real close...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are always joining the first thread in the queue. If this thread is taking a long time it might be the only thread left. I guess what you want is to start a new thread once *any* thread has completed.

I don't know why you only get an effective concurrency level of only one though.

After having looked at the doWork function I think that it is doing so little work that it is taking less work than starting a thread in the first place. Try running it with more work (1000x).

Comment: did you mix `deque` with `queue`?

Comment: The code starts to join only if `threads.size() >= maxConcurrentThreads`.

Comment: @megabyte1024 that doesn't matter because if the first thread in the deque takes much longer than the others, all the others will finish before the first one and the only one running at a time is the first one.

Comment: Actually, my recommendation is to use a thread-pool. It will handle all of this for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084777/creating-a-thread-pool-using-boost

Comment: @bamboon In fact it does not matter.

Comment: @megabyte1024 if the joined thread happens to execute a sleep(infinity) new threads will never be spawned. The concurrency level will erroneously fall to one.

Comment: @megabyte1024 If you are talking about the mixing of `queue` and `deque` then you are right in this case, however I mix them all the time, too. The names are just too similar.

Comment: each execution of `doWork` will take very nearly the same amount of time.  (In my test code, it's just adding 1000 numbers together.  in actual practice, it'll be executing a linear-time algorithm.)  So there's no reason to expect that this issue is causing the threads to all execute on one processor.  A thread pool is clearly superior to the queue implementation here, and I will look into it, but that's not addressing the central problem: _Why are all threads on one core?  How can I send threads to different cores?_

Comment: You are right. Can you post doWork in its entirety? Btw, you need to delete the completed thread objects (does not matter here).

Comment: Adding 1000 numbers together?  That thread is probably done by the time you get to creating the second thread, so the second thread may well run on the same core because that core has the process context already set.  Do some heavier work!

Comment: Adding up all the numbers to 10,000,000 is better loading - you may then have a chance to see what is going on.

Comment: I just looked at the code. I agree with @MartinJames. I added to my answer.

Comment: changing it to 10,000,000 additions yields the same (single processor) behavior.

Comment: OK, now I'm puzzled.  OK, OP code is not the usual way of distributing work to threads, but it should work.