# How to use boost::asio::io_service to dispatch jobs between C++11 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-thread

I need to perform on a multi-core architecture a huge quantity of relatively short tasks.
For this I wanted to use a fixed size thread pool and some reliable implementation of an executor.

I was reading about boost::asio and io_service in this post [How to create a thread pool using boost in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500404/how-to-create-a-thread-pool-using-boost-in-c) but this uses boost threads, while in many places my code uses the c++11 thread_local modifier for local variables (for performance reasons), hence I suppose I'm forced to use c++11 threads.

Is the boost thread implementation compatible with c++11 thread_local variables?

Is it safe to just use the io_service::run method with c++11 threads, instead that with boost::thread?

Comment: thread locals are just that. Thread locals. Boost doesn't need to support them, as long as their implementation is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to just use the io_service::run method with c++11 threads, instead that with boost::thread?

Yes, I use `std::thread` with `boost::asio` and it works fine. I also use `std::bind` instead of `boost::bind`. You can find an example [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/ASIO-with-std-thread-td4645072.html)

> Is the boost thread implementation compatible with c++11 thread_local variables?

I don't know about that, but it should be irrelevant if you use `std::thread`

Comment: i just tested and it indeed works, even though I have had some angry moments when I realized how io_service::stop() works.