# How to run a function on a separate thread, if a thread is available

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

How can I run a function on a separate thread if a thread is available, assuming that i always want *k* threads running at the same time at any point?

Here's a pseudo-code

```
For i = 1 to N
   IF numberOfRunningThreads < k
      // run foo() on another thread 
   ELSE
      // run foo()
```

In summary, once a thread is finished it notifies the other threads that there's a thread available that any of the other threads can use. I hope the description was clear.

Comment: you need a threadpool.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500404/how-to-create-a-thread-pool-using-boost-in-c

Comment: Yes, but how do I maintain the number of threads that are running? I can create 3 threads at the start, but this approach needs that I queue the job, which will be executed once a thread is available. What I want is to only queue the job only when a thread becomes available, without keeping to check the status but some sort of notification to the other threads that it is now possible to queue a job which will be immediately executed.

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach: Just *do* create the k threads and let them call foo repeatedly. You need some counter, protected against race conditions, that is decremented each time before foo is called by *any* thread. As soon as the desired number of calls has been performed, the threads will exit one after the other (incomplete/pseudo code):

```
unsigned int global_counter = n;

void fooRunner()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard g(global_counter_mutex);
            if(global_counter == 0)
                break;
            --global_counter;
        }
        foo();
    }
}

void runThreads(unsigned int n, unsigned int k)
{
    global_counter = n;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(std::min(n, k - 1));
    // k - 1: current thread can be reused, too...
    // (provided it has no other tasks to perform)
    for(auto& t : threads)
    {
        t = std::thread(&fooRunner);
    }
    fooRunner();
    for(auto& t : threads)
    {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

If you have data to pass to `foo` function, instead of a counter you could use e. g a FIFO or LIFO queue, whatever appears most appropriate for the given use case. Threads then exit as soon as the buffer gets empty; you'd have to prevent the buffer running empty prematurely, though, e. g. by prefilling all the data to be processed before starting the threads.

A variant might be a combination of both: exiting, if the global counter gets 0, waiting for the queue to receive new data e. g. via a condition variable otherwise, and the main thread continuously filling the queue while the threads are already running...

Answer (score 0):

you can use (`std::thread in <thread>`) and locks to do what you want, but it seems to me that your code could be simply become parallel using openmp like this.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(k)

#pragma omp for
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
auto t_id = omp_get_thread_num();
if (t_id < K)
   foo()
else
   other_foo()
}
```