# Can boost::asio::thread_pool be used instead of combining boost::asio::io_context with a boost::thread::thread_group?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to clear up some confusion I have. I stumbled over [boost::asio::thread_pool](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool.html) and I thought that one could use to somehow automatically combine `boost::asio::io_context` and `boost::thread::thread_group` like is often suggested ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500405/1300177) or [here](https://www.gamedev.net/blogs/entry/2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/)). It appears that this `asio`-specific pool can be used to `post` tasks to but, on the other hand, some networking types like `resolver` need to be passed an object `io_context` as a constructor parameter which `thread_pool` isn't and doesn't derive from.

Answer (score 5):

Say you have a single `io_context` object, named `ioc`.

You can create several threads, and call `ioc.run()` in each one of them. This is a blocking operation that blocks on epoll/select/kqueue. Note that `ioc` is shareable, and by calling `ioc.run()` in several threads, they implicitly belong to a thread pool to be used by `ioc`. Let's call this pool `io_threadpool`.

Now create a separate pool of threads called `compute`, that do other things. Here is what is possible:

- You can use `ioc` in threads from both pools (except for a few, like `restart()`, which require that `ioc` is not actively running).
- You can make sync I/O calls from any thread.
- You can invoke an async call like `async_read( ..., handler)` from any thread. However, the handler is only invoked in one of the `io_threadpool` threads.
- You can dispatch tasks in either thread pool, but if the task is not going to do any I/O, I expect it to be more efficient to dispatch it in the compute pool, because the system doesn't have to wake up the `epoll()`/`kqueue()`/`select()` call on which it is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

You should post your `io_context.run()` into the `thread_pool`.

Comment: So... the answer is no?

Comment: Yes, the answer is no.  You can learn more about concept-model.