# Asynchronous function calls in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous

This is some code i'm using in Java for Making Asynchronous function calls in Java  :

```
    public class AsyncLogger
    {
        public static asyncLog = null;
        public static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        public static AsyncLogger GetAsyncClass()
        {
            if(asyncLog == null)
            {
                asyncLog= new AsyncLogger();
            }
            return asyncLog;
        }


        public void WriteLog(String logMesg)
        {
            executorService.execute(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    WriteLogDB(logMesg);
                }
            });
                }

                public void ShutDownAsync()
                {
                    executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

This is a Singleton Class with static ExecutorService and WriteLogDB will be called as an Asynchronous function. So i can process my Code in WriteLogDB asynchronously without affecting the main flow.

Can i get a C++ equivalent like this ..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::thread([](){WriteLogDB(logMesg);}).detach();
```

or if you need to wait for a result:

```
auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){WriteLogDB(logMesg);});
// do stuff while that's happening
result.get();
```

If you're stuck with a pre-2011 compiler, then there are no standard thread facilities; you'll need to use a third-party library like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html), or roll you own, platform specific, threading code. Boost has a thread class similar to the new standard class:

```
boost::thread(boost::bind(WriteLogDB, logMesg)).detach();
```

Comment: Also known as `fire_and_forget([]{ WriteLogDB(logMsg); });`. :) E: Why did you change the lambda to `bind`?

Comment: @ManikandarajS: The first version certainly will. The second is implementation-defined; it might create a thread, or it might use a thread pool or something.

Comment: @Xeo: Because I'm more comfortable with `bind`. I'll put the lambda back as an alternative for those who like squiggles.

Comment: And for those who like performance, `bind` isn't the fastest thing on earth. :)

Comment: @Mike I don't want to create separate Threads for each function call, that would be difficult. I can run 3 or 4 threads in a thread Pool and try the Async call

Comment: @Xeo: I guess so; presumably, `bind` will use a function pointer, so is probably less inlineable.

Comment: @ManikandarajS: That sounds rather more difficult than just using the standard library facilities; but if implementing a thread pool sounds like fun, then go ahead.

Comment: @Mike I just want to keep the number of threads limited say 2 or 3. But the function calls may be more. ExecutorService in java service can be limited to a Single Thread and it can run Asynchronous functions in single thread from its own memory queue

Answer (score 6):

You can make asynchronous functions calls using [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) from C++11.

Comment: ...or alternatively if you don't have c++11, but do have boost, consider my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084777/creating-a-thread-pool-using-boost/4085345#4085345