# C++ ThreadPool is not running parallel

Tags: c++, concurrency, threadpool

I've tried to implement a ThreadPool, but unfortunately I'm running into some problems.

This is what I have already.

```
//includes ...

void call()
{
    std::cout << "Hi i'm thread no " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "ready " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
};

//Implementation is not shown here to reduce code
class WorkQueue {
    public:
        bool push(std::function<void()> const& value);
        void pop();
        bool empty();
};

std::condition_variable g_queuecheck;
std::mutex              g_lockqueue;
std::atomic<bool>       g_notified;

class ThreadPool
{
    public:
        ThreadPool(int iNoThread) :
            m_noThread(iNoThread)
        {
            g_notified.store(false);
            m_threads.resize(iNoThread);
            bIsReady.store(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < iNoThread; ++i)
                m_threads[i] = std::thread(&ThreadPool::run, this);
        }

        void run()
        {
            while (!bIsReady || !m_workQueue.empty())
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockqueue);
                if (m_workQueue.empty())
                {
                    while (!g_notified) // Used to avoid spurious wakeups
                    {
                        g_queuecheck.wait(locker);
                    }
                    if(!bIsReady)
                        g_notified.store(false);
                }

                m_workQueue.pop();
            }
        };

        void addWork(std::function<void()> func)
        {
            m_workQueue.push(func);
            g_notified.store(true);
            g_queuecheck.notify_one();
        }

        void join()
        {
            bIsReady.store(true);
            g_notified.store(true);
            g_queuecheck.notify_all();

            for (int i = 0; i < m_noThread; ++i)
                m_threads[i].join();
        }

        ~ThreadPool()
        {}


        WorkQueue m_workQueue;
        int m_noThread;
        std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
        std::atomic<bool> bIsReady;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        ThreadPool pool(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            pool.addWork(call); //This work is done sequentially

        pool.join();
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the work is done sequentially.

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is something else wrong with my ThreadPool?
3. Is the waiting best-practice?

Comment: where is your function actually being called in run(), all I see is only work queue pop.

Comment: It seems the actual execution of the callback is done in `WorkQueue::pop` (there doesn't seem to be any other suitable place). If so, note that this happens while `g_lockqueue` mutex is held.

Comment: You're not actually doing any work. I assume when you pop you should run the function. Make sure you run the function NOT under the lock. Also your use of `g_notified` is unnecessary and probably a pessimisation. You should just check for `m_workQueue.empty()`. Also I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `bIsReady`.

Comment: The member variables in class ThreadPool are public. Is that object-oriented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use boost::asio to implement a thread pool.  Hope this helps.  This implementation was gleaned from the [Asio Thread Pool](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes).  The key for me to get the example to work is scoping the asio::io_service::work and have the join_all outside that scope.

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>


boost::mutex output_mutex;
void call(size_t job_number)
{
    {
       boost::mutex::scoped_lock print_lock(output_mutex);
       std::cout << "Hi i'm job << " << job_number <<" and thread: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
    {
       boost::mutex::scoped_lock print_lock(output_mutex);
       std::cout << "job " << job_number << " finished. thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " ready." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t number_of_threads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    // the number of jobs does not have to equal the number of
    // threads.  they will be processed in turn.
    size_t number_of_jobs = 3 * number_of_threads;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread_group threads;
    {
        boost::scoped_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > work( new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service) );
        for(size_t t = 0; t < number_of_threads; t++)
        {
            threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        }

        // post the jobs for work
        // notice that the thread id is reused
        for( size_t t = 0; t < number_of_jobs; t++ )
        {
            io_service.post(boost::bind(call,t) );
        }
    }
    threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've used this code (pattern) to thread functions including class methods that require parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I fix this?

You don't show any work actually being done, only `pop` being called. Assuming that really executes the function, you should note that your `std::unique_lock` is still in scope when you do this, so it's synchronized. You need to have *released* the lock for the calls to be concurrent, which means that locker must be out of scope.

For example,

```
    { // begin locker scope
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockqueue);
        if (m_workQueue.empty())
        {

            while (!g_notified) // used to avoid spurious wakeups 
            {
                g_queuecheck.wait(locker);
            }
            if(!bIsReady)
                g_notified.store(false);
        }
    } // end locker scope
    m_workQueue.pop();
```

Note that now, your pop method will run the functions in parallel, but it will also be mutating the queue in parallel. This is  a problem. You'll need to do something like: move the function into a local variable, and then pop, while holding the mutex; then call the function outside the locker scope.

> 2. Is something else wrong with my ThreadPool?

You're using globals, which is ugly, and your variables are poorly named: it isn't at all clear what `g_notified` and `bIsReady` are intended to mean.

> 3. Is the waiting best-practice?

No. Even apart from the actual bug, its intent is obscure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `run` function: The `g_lockqueue` is locked for too long. It is locked as long as `locker` is in scope, so `g_lockqueue` is locked when `pop` is called.
But, because `pop` and `empty` must not be executed concurrently, you need to return the "Work" while locked, then release the lock, and finally execute the work.

`run` could look like this:

```
void run()
{
    while (!bIsReady || !m_workQueue.empty())
    {
        Work work;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockqueue);
            if (m_workQueue.empty())
            {

                while (!g_notified) // used to avoid spurious wakeups 
                {
                    g_queuecheck.wait(locker);
                }
                if(!bIsReady)
                    g_notified.store(false);
            }
            work = m_workQueue.pop();  // get the work to be done while locked
        } // g_lockqueue released here
        work.do();  // do the work
    }
};
```