# is there a async thread pool available in boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I am building a system in which i will need to submit small tasks and wait for their completion in main thread.
I have found a thread pool implementation https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL.

The problem is the compiler (i have gcc 4.4.7 redhat) doesnt support the c++11 futures and its not going to be updated any sooner. I tried to change the above implementation to use boost future/async etc but i am getting all sort of issues for e.g. on windows boost::async doesnt support boost::launch::deferred policy and crashes.

Is there a available thread pool which i can use? Or if someone can guide me to build a thread pool where i can wait in the main thread for all the tasks to be done like in case of future.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084777/creating-a-thread-pool-using-boost/4085345#4085345

Comment: Consider OpenMP as an alternative. Maybe it will match your needs

Comment: Just to make Nim's comment less link-only: Boost.Asio has [threadpools](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) that can be used.

Comment: thanks all for the advices.